# How do I display images from this XML feed?

Tags: php, xml, curl, feed

hoping someone can help on this. i'm using the following script to display data from a feed on my website. for some reason i can't get the images in the feed to display. i've noticed that the images addresses have a space in them and i'm wondering if this is the problem. however i have changed the feed and replaced the spaces with '%20' in the hope that they would then display. still no luck. any ideas?

```
            <?php

            # INSTANTIATE CURL.
            $curl = curl_init();

            # CURL SETTINGS.
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.dpm.uk.com/feeds/rss/product-syndication.ashx?pgid=6&feed=opt1");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);

            # GRAB THE XML FILE.
            $xml = curl_exec($curl);

            curl_close($curl);

            # SET UP XML OBJECT.
            $xmlObj = simplexml_load_string( $xml );

            $tempCounter = 0;

            foreach ( $xmlObj->item as $item )
            {                    
                # DISPLAY ONLY 10 ITEMS.
                if ( $tempCounter < 20 )
                {
                   echo "
                   <div class=\"feed-item\">
                   Title: {$item -> title}
                   Year: {$item -> Year}
                   Colours: {$item -> Colours}
                   Size: {$item -> Size}
                   Available: {$item -> Available}
                   Image: {$item -> Images}
                <br>

                   </div>
                   ";

                }

                $tempCounter += 1;
            }

            ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+xml+feed+php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$img = $item->Images->img[0]->attributes();

echo "
  <div class=\"feed-item\">
    Title: {$item->title}
    Year: {$item->Year}
    Colours: {$item->Colours}
    Size: {$item->Size}
    Available: {$item->Available}
    Image: {$img['src']}
    <br>
  </div>
";
```

**Update:**

To display the image:

```
echo "Image: <img src=\"{$img['src']}\" width=\"{$img['width']}\" height=\"{$img['height']}\" />";
```

To diplay all images:

```
foreach ($item->Images as $img) {
  $img = $img->attributes();
  echo "Image: <img src=\"{$img['src']}\" width=\"{$img['width']}\" height=\"{$img['height']}\" />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Using the above code ive managed to display the src of the image. So the feed displays like this:

`Title: Rapida 105-10 SW (10+0/5+5)`
`Year: 2008`
`Colours: 10 Colour`
`Size: 740x1050mm`
`Available: Immediately`
`Image: http://www.dpm.uk.com/images/May 12/2008_KBA_105_a.jpg`

how do i add this into some markup so that the image displays? Also there are 3-4 images contained within the <Images> tag of the XML feed. Can I grab these too instead of just the first one?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$data = file_get_contents("http://www.dpm.uk.com/feeds/rss/product-syndication.ashx?pgid=6&feed=opt1");
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($xml->item as $item) {

    if ($counter < 20){
             echo "<div class=\"feed-item\">
                Title: " . $item->title . ", " . "
                Year:  " . $item->Year . "
        <br></div>";
    }
}
?>
```

tested it works

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Unfortunately that doesn't appear to be working. When I add your changes to the code no feed information is displayed. Any ideas? Should I be using any of the 'Curl' code at the top of the script? Is there a better way of doing it? Thanks again.

Comment: u can try do $xml = file_get_contents($your_link) its should work